# How to use print statements in a for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to print out reasons why some files are not passing my condition but I am stuck.

Currently this is my code:

```
for (i in files)) {
  if (file.info(files$file_size > 5 & !files %in% geography)) {
    new_file <- read.csv(files)
  } else {
    print(files, “is less than required size") 
    next
  }
```

The issue I am having is that for the files that do not match both criteria, it is writing the file name and then the statement “is less than required size”. Hence something is wrong with my loop.

My question is, how do I make it print those files that do not meet size and also print the files not included in geography accurately? Where should I add the print statement?
Thank you

Comment: within the loop you need to replace `files` by `i` so you're checking the specific file

Comment: thank you for your response. However I tried it and I am getting an error. Is there something else you would recommend I try?